# How to write a BIOS program that runs before the OS?

Tags: scripting, boot, bios, low-level

I am trying to write a script that is executed before Windows is booted on my Computer.

I have already developed a simple Linux bash script to accomplish this, but I would like to improve and take it further. The problem with using a Linux script is that it adds quite a bit of time to the boot sequence as Linux has to start/initialize then execute it, which is obviously undesirable.

What I would like to do is write a low-level program (assembly? machine code?) which BIOS would read, execute, and then continue to Windows(or any other OS).

Is there a way to run scripts in that fashion without the presence of a OS and if so what language or resources should I consider.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054578/run-a-program-without-an-operating-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to write "scripts" to do what you describe.

It is, however, possible to create a chain loader and have the chain loader do anything you want it to in the first stages before loading Windows.  [The accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764183/print-a-number-in-nasm-building-an-x86-bootsector/30770127#30770127) will get you started down this road.

You would want to consider Assembly Language.  You didn't specify an architecture, but saying "Windows" implies x86 or x86_64.

All of that said, I suspect your question will be closed since it is enormously broad.

Comment: Long time lurker, first time poster. Will try to be more specific next time.

Comment: Perhaps in a UEFI system you could write something like that without using assembly.